# passport-local-mongoose setPassword not working

Tags: node.js, mongodb, token, passport.js

Am trying to reset the user password, and am using passport-local-mongoose, and i send the reset link through mail for them and a token is added to the link also. the link opens but when user hits the reset button it throws up an error in my command line **null**

```
passortLocalMongoose = require("passport-local-mongoose")
var UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    email: {type: String, unique: true},
    password: String,
    resetPasswordToken: String,
    resetpasswordExpires: Date
})

UserSchema.plugin(passortLocalMongoose);
mongoose.model("User", UserSchema )

app.post('/reset/:token', function(req, res, next) {
    asynco.waterfall([
        function(done) {
            User.findOne({resetPasswordToken :req.params.token, resetPasswordExpires: { $gt: Date.now()}}, function(err, user) {
                if(!user){
                  console.log(err);
                  req.flash('error', 'Password reset token is invalid or has expired')
                  return res.redirect('back')
                }
                if(req.body.password === req.body.confirm) {
                    user.setPassword(req.body.password, function(err,user){
                        if(err){
                            console.log(err)
                            req.flash('error', 'Sorry something went wrong')
                            return res.redirect('back')
                        } else {
                            user.resetPasswordToken = undefined;
                            user.resetPasswordExpires = undefined;

                            user.save(function(err){
                                req.login(user, function(err){
                                    done(err,user)
                                })
                            })
                        }
                    })
                } else {
                    req.flash('error', 'Passwords do not match')
                    res.redirect('back');
                }
            })
        }
     ])
})
```

**The error am getting when user hits the submit button**

```
null
```

if i debug it just after the **if(req.body.password == req.body.confirm)** and type arguments it shows the two inputs are null but i type req.body it shows the two passwords

Comment: Just add a `debugger` statement before your `                    `user.setPassword(req.body.password, function(err,user){` line and open up your url in chrome (ensure that you have the `Developer Console` opened as well), and when it hits the debug point, in the console window, just type `arguments` and see what it returns.

Comment: I had to install locus. I debugged it using locus it prints out { '0': null, '1': null }. that means that the password and confirm are null, but what is the reason behind this? @DavidR

Comment: But if i type req.body it logs out { password: 'bito', confirm: 'bito' } so the req.body isn't empty either. any help is appreciated :) @DavidR

Answer (score 0):

You forgot the semicolon. Is that your problem ?

```
app.post('/reset/:token', function(req, res, next) {
asynco.waterfall([
    function(done) {
        User.findOne({resetPasswordToken :req.params.token, resetPasswordExpires: { $gt: Date.now()}}, function(err, user) {
            if(err){
              console.log(err);
              req.flash('error', 'Password reset token is invalid or has expired')
              return res.redirect('back')
            }
            if(req.body.password === req.body.confirm) {
                user.setPassword(req.body.password, function(err,user){
                    if(err){
                        console.log(err)
                        req.flash('error', 'Sorry something went wrong')
                        return res.redirect('back')
                    } else {
                        user.resetPasswordToken = undefined;
                        user.resetPasswordExpires = undefined;

                        user.save(function(err){
                            req.login(user, function(err){
                                done(err,user)
                            })
                        })
                    }
                });
            } else {
                req.flash('error', 'Passwords do not match')
                res.redirect('back');
            }
        });
    }
 ])
})
```

Comment: i don't see the semicolon you added please can you mark it out @phenric

Comment: Sure ! just before the last else, you wrote }) but I think it should be }); 
 `});
            } else {`

Comment: kk i have seen that but that's not the issue it throws up same error anyway   
  @phenric   :) for your reply

Answer (score 0):

Based on your information and code I can help you with assumptions only, provide more information and I'll update the answer.

Are you sure that user is found with your criteria?

```
User.findOne({
  resetPasswordToken: req.params.token,
  resetPasswordExpires: { $gt: Date.now()}
}, function(err, user) {
  if (err) {} // Handle the error
  if (!user) {} // User is not found, but no error as well
  // only then try to call setPassword
});
```

I bet, your criteria is wrong and that is the reason why Mongo returns `null` instead of User record.

All you need to do to solve the problem is to debug that everything is writes in database and that your criteria is able to match the correct user. Everything else will work then.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, yeah the user is found in the database cause i send them the link through a mail using a token, so the user can't be found if the token stored in the database does not match and thats same thing with the post route. @ghaiklor

Comment: setPassword is a function that comes with passport-local-mongoose i don't know if am using a lower version. but i have updated my question by adding my user schema @ghaiklor

Comment: You need to be sure that uses is exists, because Mongo returns `null` if record is not found. I believe, that your criteria is not matching for the user you are looking for.

Comment: I mean, yours error message says that there is an attempt to call `setPassword` function on a `null` which is your user as you expect, but it's not.

Comment: You have a typo in `resetpasswordExpires` in your schema and the criteria. But, really, we already pointed you to the right direction, try to fix it on your own. Updated the answer.

Comment: Is like I need a sleep to cool my head. thanks for that never found i typed the letter 'p' in small lettter you have tried let me work things out. happy coding mate @ghaiklor